# Display latest conversation after reopening IM window

Tags: ubuntu, pidgin, chat

I would like to see the last conversation when closing and reopening an IM Window in Pidgin. I can't find an option in preferences. I use:

```
Pidgin 2.10.9 (libpurple 2.10.9)
```

I explicitly don't want to open the separate log window. At least, I don't want to pidign to display the whole log in the IM window, but only the latest conversation (like Spark does).
This would be very handy in case of closing an IM window by accident.

How to achieve this?

Comment: I don't have `pidgin` in front of me to check, but IIRC this functionality is part of the *History plugin*- do you have that enabled?

Comment: No problem, since that sorted it I will write it up as an answer in case anyone comes a-lookin' and misses the comments :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is part of the `History plugin`:

> Shows recently logged conversations in new conversations.

Plugins are accessible by hitting `Ctrl+u`, and can be enabled via checkbox:

[image: Pidgin plug-ins screen]